# How do I sort a PHP associative array first by value, then by key?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, associative-array

I have an associative array in which the keys are strings and the values are integers. I'm wanting to first of all sort the array by the values and then sort elements with the same value by their keys. I've managed to sort the array by the values using asort() but haven't worked out how to then sort by the keys.

Any Help?

Thanks

Comment: Use `ksort`/`uksort` to sort by key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
uksort(
    $myArray,
    function ($a, $b) use ($myArray) {
        if ($myArray[$a] == $myArray[$b]) {
            return strcmp($a, $b);
        }
        return ($myArray[$a] < $myArray[$b]) ? -1 : 1;
   }
);
```